# Access struct data after JSON parse, Swift

Tags: swift, struct, get, alamofire, codable

I'm stuck on the following:
I've run this code

```
AF.request(url, method: .get).responseDecodable(of: UserInfo.self) { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

And I parsed JSON into this struct:

```
struct UserInfo: Codable {
let totalCount: Int
let incompleteResults: Bool
let items: [Item]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case totalCount = "total_count"
    case incompleteResults = "incomplete_results"
    case items
}}

struct Item: Codable {

let id: Int
let userName: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case userName = "userName"
}}
```

How do I access, for example, the userName field?

The struct is outside my class and I would like to have this filed on another .swift file

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you want to use is a callback to send the data back to the function that calls the networkRequestFunction.

```
  func makeRequest() {
            someRequest(url: "thisURL") { (userInfo, error) in
                guard let userInfo = userInfo else {
                    // present error
                    return
                }

                // Now you have your userStruct
                print(userInfo)
            }
        }


        func someRequest(url: String, callback: @escaping ((UserInfo?, AFError?) -> ())) {
                AF.request(url, method: .get).responseDecodable(of: UserInfo.self) { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let info):
// This is where i missed that you already had decoded it, no need to guard let here
                        callback(info, nil)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        callback(nil, error)
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answers, but I'm quiete a beginner, and I'm not very good w Closures.
I get the following error on data : ***Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UserInfo'***

And just to be sure, with ***Model*** you mean my struct ***UserInfo***?

Comment: btw with my code in the debugger I see my UserInfo with the fields I want, but I'm not able to access them

Comment: I apologize, i misread some of your code. i have completly edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for your time man! You are very nice!!
May I ask one more question?

What if I need to access the ***username*** field in another .swift file? 

Your code is working, this is outside the scope of my question!

Comment: I can't figure out how to access username field neither in the main file to be honest ...

Comment: If you have the `UserInfo` object, it is in the array of items. but the first username is: `userInfo.items.first!.username`, to print them all you `userInfo.items.map{print($0.username)}` good luck mate

Comment: May I ask one last question? In ***makeRequest()*** I have my userStruct, but how do I access it externally? Do I save my data in my struct? I can't access them

Im sorry, I'm a beginner and I'm so stucked on this

Comment: I really can't understand how to get this field from my struct or without a function ...

Comment: @jamesCode To have this data externally especially since it is an User object most people create something called a `singleton`, the other solution that is safer but more difficult to pull of is called `dependency injection` check them out :)